# How to scroll something through an LED matrix (Raspberry Pi / Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, matrix, raspberry-pi, led

I arranged a matrix of LEDs (12x12) which are individually adressable. I also wrote down patterns of which LEDs have to be lighted when I want a certain letter to show up, like this:

```
letter_a = ['00111100', '01000010', '01000010', '01111110', '01000010', '01000010', '01000010', '01000010']
```

And I can display that without issue. What I want to accomplish is for these patterns to scroll through the matrix from right to left so someone can read a text on what is essentially a scrolling 144 pixel display.

My problem is that I am fairly new to programming and don't know how I can get away from addressing each pixel to a certain LED rather than just treating the pattern as a whole - no matter where on the matrix it should light up - so I can move it around.

Comment: Hello Mojo, and welcome to the site.  As you have it written your question is too broad for us to be able to help you, are you able to narrow it down to a more specific question?  You can also see other guidelines on how to ask here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I thought about how I can narrow the question down and I'll give it a try!
`letter_a = ["00111100,01000010,01000010,01111110,01000010,01000010,01000010,01000010"]`
this is how I want to write a letter on my LED panel. Each 1 or 0 representing one LED. I have no trouble displaying this but what I want to do is move this letter over the display without having to write every single LED.
I can't think of a way to program this.

Comment: If it was me I would probably do it like you're doing it now- manually make the LED arrays for each letter.  You can look up the manual LED list easily with a dictionary.

Comment: I already have an array for each letter, the problem is how i can scroll the letters over the panel without having to write every single LED for every single frame. Without scrolling I cant display text on the 12x12 pixel big "display", just one letter at a time.

Comment: I notice that your example for `A` is 8x8, not 12x12- is that right?

Comment: Thanks for editing my question! Yes, the letters I wanted to use are 8x8, I would place them in the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you keep the state of the LED's in a 'frame' that is structured like your `letter_a`.  This will allow you to modify it easily and re-display it however you like.

After that, it is just a matter of editing your frame every time you have a movement.  You could do something like this:

```
def nextFrame(current_frame, queue):
    for row in range(0, len(current_frame)):
        new_row = current_frame[row][1:] + queue[row][0]
        current_frame[row] = new_row
        queue[row] = queue[row][1:]
    return current_frame, queue
```

which you could use something like this:

```
letter_a = ['00111100', '01000010', '01000010', '01111110', '01000010', '01000010', '01000010', '01000010']
current_frame = ['10000001', '01000010', '00100100', '00011000', '00011000', '00100100', '01000010', '10000001']
queue = ['00111100', '01000010', '01000010', '01111110', '01000010', '01000010', '01000010', '01000010']
while len(queue[0]):
    display(current_frame)
    current_frame, queue = nextFrame(current_frame, queue)
```